# Configure KnpPaginator to work with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, knppaginator

[image: Vendor folder]
i'm trying to apply twitter bootstrap css style to my knp pagination without modifying the vendor.
Is there a way to configure KnpPaginator so to detect existing bootstrap css style sheets?because as the screenshot shows, it is build to work with bootstrap.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

@Derick F: thank you a lot, i found an other way :

i just replaced:

```
pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig
```

with

```
pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig
```

its the default template included in knp bundle.

Comment: oh lol, well then i didn't even know they had that included, but that's great to know.  It seems one key differences are that they don't handle window resizing as well as my template.  If you view the paginator in a web page and then resize your window down to a phone screen size you'll notice that the paginator ends up taking two lines instead of one.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, in your <kbd>config.yml</kbd> and your `knp_paginator` settings:

```
knp_paginator:
    template:
         pagination: AcmeBundle:Common:paginator-bootstrap.html.twig
```

and then in <kbd>paginator-bootstrap.html.twig</kbd>

```html
{% if pageCount > 1 %}
    <ul class="pagination">
    {% if first is defined and current != first %}
        <li class="first">
            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): first})) }}">
                &lt;&lt;
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if previous is defined %}
        <li class="previous">
            <a class="hidden-xs" href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): previous})) }}">
                &lt;
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% for page in pagesInRange %}
        {% if page != current %}
            <li class="page">
                <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): page})) }}">
                    {{ page }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="current active">
                <a>
                    {{ page }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if next is defined %}
        <li class="next">
            <a class="hidden-xs" href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): next})) }}">
                &gt;
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if last is defined and current != last %}
        <li class="last">
            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): last})) }}">
                &gt;&gt;
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```