# how to custom the buttons of the knp paginator

Tags: symfony, pagination, symfony-2.6, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

I integrated knp bundle in my project but the buttons of the paginator is like that

[image]

how can i make the button like in my template

[image]

```
<div id="blog_pagination" class="pagination pagination-centered clearfix">
                    <a class="next page-numbers" href="#"><i class="ci_icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
                    <a class="page-numbers" href="#">2</a>
                    <a class="next page-numbers" href="#"><i class="ci_icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure KnpPaginator to work with Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035404/configure-knppaginator-to-work-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: this this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23035644/1865655

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, in the config file:

```
// app/config/config.yml

knp_paginator:
        page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
        default_options:
            page_name: page                # page query parameter name
            sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
            sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
            distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
        template:
            pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
            sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig # sort link template
```

change the default template for the boostrap template:

```
pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig
```

for (boostrap 3)

```
pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig
```

or (boostrap 1 and 2)

```
pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_pagination.html.twig
```